# How to handle 404 missing PathVariable error in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, controller, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an application with multiple modules. Some are not reactive, and `api-gateway` is reactive (because of Spring Cloud implementation). Security and some header filters are on the `api-gateway` side.

I have a module `search-services`, it provides an endpoint `/search/{id}/info` with path variable `id`.

**The problem is:** `/search//info` returns *standard 404 response body*, while I expect it to be *custom 400 body*.

Exception handling in `api-gateway`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
// omitted some methods which are surely not related to this issue

    // 500
    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleServerErrorException(ServerErrorException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return processException(
                exception, MsgErrorCode.SYSTEM_ERROR,
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exchange
        );
    }

    // validation by annotations, param types
    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleWebExchangeBindException(WebExchangeBindException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return processException(
                exception, MsgErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR,
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exchange
        );
    }

    // missing required request param
    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleMissingRequestValueException(MissingRequestValueException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return processException(
                exception, MsgErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR,
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exchange
        );
    }

    // missing required headers like Content-Length
    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleServerWebInputException(ServerWebInputException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return processException(
                exception, MsgErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR,
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exchange
        );
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(DataNotFoundException.class)
    private Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleDataNotFound(ServerWebExchange exchange, DataNotFoundException exception) {
        return processException(exception, MsgErrorCode.DATA_NOT_FOUND, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, exchange);
    }

    private Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> processException(
            Throwable exception, MsgErrorCode errorType, HttpStatus httpStatus, ServerWebExchange exchange
    ) {
        Mono<ErrorResponse> errorResponse = ... // logic of creating a custom response body

        return errorResponse.map(body ->
                ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(body)
        );
    }
}
```

For exceptions which reactive GlobalExceptionHandler cannot handle:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public class ReactiveExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    protected Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {
        // some logic to create a response
    }
}
```

Handler for non-reactive mvc services like `search-services`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
// this helps with "/search/   /info", but doesn't handle the case "/search//info"
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingPathVariable(MissingPathVariableException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        return processException(exception, MsgErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

// omitted some methods which are surely not related to this issue

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        return processException(exception, MsgErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Throwable.class, SystemException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleThrowable(WebRequest request, Throwable throwable) {
        return processException(throwable, MsgErrorCode.SYSTEM_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> processException(
            Throwable exception, MsgErrorCode errorType, HttpStatus httpStatus, WebRequest webRequest
    ) {
        // custom response body is identical as in api-gateway
    }
}
```

I debugged non-reactive `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (which I inherit from), it doesn't intercept the exception and I don't know the type of exception. I cannot debug interaction of `api-gateway` and `search-services`. Because I debug locally without Kubernetes.